# Declare an `any` value as a class

Tags: typescript

There is a small, ad-hoc script I'm forced to `require()` (*not* `import`) and I want to wrap it in a typescript file with an adjacent `declare class` statement.

```js
declare class MyCache<K, T> {
    constructor(numItems: number);
    get(key: K): T;
    set(key: K, val: T): void;
}

const Cache = require('./my-cache-module');
export default Cache as MyCache<K, T>; // <---- not quite right...

// intended to be used as:
//
//    const cache: MyCache<string, string> = new MyCache(100);
//    cache.set('foo', 'bar');
//    cache.get('foo'); //-> 'bar'
```

How do I tell Typescript that `Cache` is not an instance of `MyCache`, but is instead the **actual** implementation of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type assert to `typeof MyClass` instead. The class name is the instance type and `typeof Class` is the type for the class itself.

```
 export default cache as typeof MyCache;
```